# How to trigger Click on enter button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am working on a search component in which auto suggestion comes when you type just like google. when i am clicking on autosuggestion it search fine. but when i use enter button instead of click it doesn't work. here is my code for click

```
function initSearchAutoClickable(resize, emchange){
    $("body").on("click", ".ui-menu-item > a", function (event) {
        $('.search .search-go').trigger('click');
    });
}
```

Does anyone have idea how to make the same for enter button. .search-go is button on which search fires

Comment: This [link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1525-jquery-s-event-triggering-order-of-default-behavior-and-triggerhandler.htm) may help

Answer (score 1):

Use [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event and check the pressed button by [keyCode](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/) or [which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

```
$("body").on("keyup", ".ui-menu-item > a", function (event) {
        if(event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13){
          $('.search .search-go').trigger('click');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Write code with :

```
$(document).keypress(function (event) {
 if (event.which == 13)  //Event for "Enter" key
 {
   //Write your code here.
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, you want to run the same code but when you press Enter, right?

So you need to do:

```
// Attach event Keypress to your search text box

$(someElementWhereYouPressEnter).on('keypress', onKeyPress);

// Handle keypress - check if is enter

function onKeyPress(e) {
    if ( e.which == 13 ) {

          // handle Enter press
          $('.search .search-go').trigger('click');

    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here u have example. This must work.

http://jsfiddle.net/TDf9p/

Look on this:

```
        $(Input).autocomplete({ 
            source: function (request, response) {
                do something
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
               do something
            }
            , change: function (event, ui) {
                do something
            }
            , focus: function (event, ui) {
               do something
            }
```

Try use some event and do what u need in event. Debug your code and look when u want do something.

If this not help look here:
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-search